# How to delay data shown on scene?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, queue

Description:

I have a *StackPane* as parent container (display) and my components are extending *Region* and kept in a *ConcurrentLinkedQueue*. The display of the components are not a problem, even the animation work as I wanted in sync with a timeline (the timeline records the whole process. E.g. min 2 -> Circle pop's up and does some fading + transition, etc.). All nice until now.

Now my problem comes: first of all I want after I consume and play this component to delete it from the display and from the Queue.

Second thing, now when I run this and I have two components that they are at the same time they run together in parallel, even though they are polled from queue (that I don't understand). So I need something that delays or waits until the first component was played, after this delete this component and play the next.

Any suggestion will be awesome!

```
        //show message
    public void showMessages() {
            while(!messageQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    playMessage(messageQueue.poll());
            }      
    }

    /**
     * Searches for the source and target component, finds the connection points and prepares the message to be played  
     * @param mess Visual message node, that will appear on dashboard
     * If no source and target component will be found this will return without doing anything
     */
    public void playMessage(MessageNodeVGT mess) {
            //get the source and the target of the message
            CompNodeVGT source=getComponent(mess, SOURCE);
            CompNodeVGT target=getComponent(mess, TARGET);
            if(source==null || target == null) {
                    return;
            }
            Point2D sourcePoint=get2DPoint(source.impl_getShape(),target.impl_getShape());
            Point2D targetPoint=get2DPoint(target.impl_getShape(),source.impl_getShape());
            mess.setSourceCoordinates(sourcePoint);
            mess.setTargetCoordinates(targetPoint);
            instance.getChildren().add(mess.createPath());
            instance.getChildren().add(mess);
            mess.play();
    }
```

Comment: For your first problem, can't you just remove the components from the *PARENT* node ? For your second problem, show us some code !

Comment: I'm removing the component from parent, but it removes before finishing the animation. About the code: the project is quite large, I will try to come back with some relevant code.

Comment: Can I have the code where you remove the components as well ?

Comment: For your second issue, play() is an asynchronous call, so the thread inside the `while` loop goes back after calling `play()` ! Try using `onFinshed` EventHandler !

Comment: I tried also with a Lock, a Semaphore ... and didn't work + setOnFinished ...that's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that I have two timelines (one general for the whole application and one local for the animation/s) the lock or other technique didn't help. Here it's why:

1st local animation ~ 3seconds (duration)

2nd local animation ~ 3seconds (duration)

general timeline: |-----10s----20s---x-x2---..

let's say x=22s =2200 millis, this is when the 1st animation pops up if the second animation will be at x2 and if this x2 is in between 1 millis - 1000 millis (even more) I will see this as a parallel event, even this is not completely true.

What I did? I just paused the general timeline until the 1st animation finishes, then on setOnFinish I just resume the general timeline.

This is not a perfect answer, because actually with this Pause you lose some time in the case if you are trying to follow some event in Real time.

I'm open to other solutions, hope this helps others too.